# Same value of transformations but different order. Why the rotation degree is different?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform, css-transforms

You can see the same transformations, only thing which differs is order of them.

When the order of them is different, rotate will animate `(360-0)%360`deg.But  when the order of them is same too, rotate will animate `(360-0)`deg. I know I should ensure that the order and value are the same. 
But I want to know why different animations only happen on the rotate. How did this be calculated ?

```css
.test {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: rotate(0) scale(.5);
}
/*css1*/

.test:hover {
  transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
}
/*css2*/

#btn:hover+.test {
  transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">css2</button>
<div class="test">
  css1
</div>
```

[Demo is here](https://jsfiddle.net/1sf8sydh/)

Comment: Nice question! I've modified my answer slightly to cut out the extra portions which aren't really required for the answer. The crux of the answer still remains the same though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ***order matters to a very great extent for CSS transforms***. Please have a look at the four points specified in the [Interpolation of Transforms](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#interpolation-of-transforms) section in the W3C Transform Specs (***especially Point 4***) and after that have a look at the [Interpolation of Matrices](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#matrix-interpolation) section.

Below is an excerpt from the Interpolation of Transforms section without examples (emphasis mine):

> When animating or transitioning transforms, the transform function lists must be interpolated. For interpolation between one transform from-transform and a second transforms to-transform, the rules described below are applied.
>
> If both the from- and to-transform are none:
>
> - There is no interpolation necessary. The computed value stays none.
>
> If one of the from- or to-transforms is none.
>
> - The value none is replaced by an equivalent identity transform function list for the corresponding transform function list. Both transform function lists get interpolated following the next rule.
>
> If from- and to-transform have the same number of transform functions, each transform function pair has either the same name, or is a derivative of the same primitive.
>
> - Interpolate each transform function pair as described in Interpolation of transform functions. The computed value is the resulting transform function list.
>
> ***In all other cases***:
>
> - The ***transform functions of each transform function list*** on the from- and to-transform get post multiplied and ***converted into 4x4 matrices***. Each of the matrices gets interpolated following the instructions in Interpolation of matrices. The computed value is the transform function matrix if both initial matrices can be represented by a correlating 3x2 matrix and matrix3d otherwise.

---

#### Case 1: Order is different

Based on Interpolation of Transforms section, our test element ***satisfies point 4*** because neither start or end transform value is none and they are ***not in same order*** or is a derivative of the same primitive (that is, basically, they are different types of transforms).

So, the transforms specified for the default and `:hover` states are converted into a matrix and is then interpolated using Interpolation of matrices.

The element's default transform was a `rotate(0) scale(0.5)` which in matrix form is `matrix(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0)` and the modified transform is `scale(1) rotate(360deg)` which is `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)`. As you can note from the example provided under [Interpolation of Matrices](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#matrix-interpolation) section, the information about the one turn gets lost because 360deg is nothing but 0deg in matrix representation. Thus the element only grows and doesn't rotate.

---

#### Case 2: Order is same

This is pretty straightforward. As you'd have guessed, it satisfies point 3 in Interpolation of Transforms and is hence not converted into a matrix. It is directly interpolated. So the `rotate` transform's value is constantly incremented from 0 to 360 inline with the duration of the transition and its timing function. So we get to see the actual rotation also in addition to the grow effect.